# How to create fileserver for a web application

Tags: java, php, authentication, networking, ftp

I have two servers.

Server A: Tomcat+Oracle: It contains web application code. Webapp is deployed on this server.

Server B: Supports PHP + MySQL + Large disk storage space. This is fileserver for the web app running on server A.

At present all users upload files on server A and server A uses FTP connection to save them on B.
Similarly for downloading A fetches file from B using FTP then sends the file to browser. But this increases network overhead for server A.

Is any any secure way in which only logged in user can download their files by directly accessing some URL of server B?

Comment: is server a and b hosted togeather ?

Comment: Both servers are in different box and in fact in different timezones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a system of short lived one time tokens. Server A for authentication, Server B for the token store and file server.

A client, once authenticated, requests a file from Server A. Server A then requests a one-time-token and URL from Server B for the given file name. Server B generates a token and URL and returns to Server A, which is in turn returned to the client.

The client can now, using the given URL and token, request the file from Server B. Server B will check that the token has not been used or expired and that the file requested matches the one the token was issued for.

Comment: Is there any existing framework which provides similar kind of support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, first you need to implement web-services in order to make connection between servers.

then once the user logged in server A and attempts to upload/download the file, the server A just sends a token key(like cookie)/a key to the server B, so server B will be ensure about the authentication, and finally server A redirect the user to server B for direct connection to cause the decrease load in server A.

in fact server A and B should communicate with each other about logged user and accessibility, and what if clients request the file before authenticate, so here server B redirect to server A for authentication, then comes back for file up/down.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of Martyn Roberts I recommend to use nginx and ngx_http_secure_download_module for this task.